# Despite everything, I still can't get the create command to work on PhoneGap

Tags: java, html, cordova

I've installed the Java development Kit, Apache Ant, Android Development Kit and I've followed this tutorial http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html

When I open the command prompt and navigate to phongeap\lib\android\bin, if I type Java, the right information is displayed to indicate it's installed. When I type Javac, again everything is good. When I type ant, everything is good. When I type adb, fine and when I type android, it's fine. Everything is installed however I still can't get the "create" command to work. When I type it in, I get the same error seen here:

[image: the error message I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added global variables in "PATH" of your computer?

Richt click on computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Path